# [Java]Why does the initial for loop starts with index i=0 post the break in else condition

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a solution to merge two sorted arrays to a single sorted array.
I tried to implement a code but it does not work. The issue that I am seeing here is after my outer for loop reaches the limit of array2.length(), it still gets started from i=0. Can someone please help explain whats wrong in this piece of code?

```
List<Integer> mergedArray = new ArrayList<>();
int counter = 0;

public List<Integer> getMergedArray(List<Integer> array1, List<Integer> array2) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = counter; j < array2.size(); j++) {
            if (array1.get(i) > array2.get(j)) {
                mergedArray.add(array2.get(j));
                counter++;
            } else {
                mergedArray.add(array1.get(i));
                System.out.println("i "  +i);
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    return mergedArray;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of sorting you're doing?

Comment: Why is i=0 wrong? You first added all elements from array2 that are smaller than array1[0], then add array1[0], and then do the same for array1[1], etc...

Comment: BTW, this looks like the merge sort algorithm.
It only works if array1 and array2 are already sorted.
Can you give an example where it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @GreyFairer I am adding element whichever is smaller from array1 or array2 to the third array such that eventually I have shifted all the elements in sorted order to the third array.
The reason I have taken counter is, I dont need to start the inner loop from 0 but only with the value where counter is set to since those elements are already been transferred to the third element

Comment: List<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<>();
        arr1.add(2);
        arr1.add(5);
        List<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();
        arr2.add(4);
        arr2.add(6);
        arr2.add(9);
My output when these arrays are used is [2, 4, 5, 2, 5]. Not sure why does the outer for loop starts with i=0 again post it reaches the end of length of array1

Comment: Hey @learner your logic is wrong here, you can run 2 for loops inside a for loop to find the smallest number and then you can add that number in 3rd array list

Comment: A) dont put more information (esp **code**)) into comments. Always edit+update your question instead. B) hint: you dont need two for loops. You need ONE while loop that iterates on BOTH lists at the same time. C) be precise about wording, you have Lists here, not arrays. Arrays are something very different!

Answer (score 0):

I think you called the same method twice, without resetting the counter or the previous mergedArray.

You should declare those inside the method.

Additionally, after reaching the end of array1, you should check if there are remaining elements in array2, and vice-versa:

```
public List<Integer> getMergedArray(List<Integer> array1, List<Integer> array2) {
    
    List<Integer> mergedArray = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = counter; j < array2.size(); j++) {
            if (array1.get(i) > array2.get(j)) {
                mergedArray.add(array2.get(j));
                counter++;
            } else {
                mergedArray.add(array1.get(i));
                System.out.println("i "  +i);
                break;
            }

        }
        if(counter >= array2.size()) {
            mergedArray.add(array1.get(i));
        }

    }
    for (int j = counter; j < array2.size(); j++) {
        mergedArray.add(array2.get(j));
    }


    return mergedArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @GreyFairer 
Could you please help me understand this " I think you called the same method twice, without resetting the counter or the previous mergedArray."

Comment: @learner I'm actually not quite sure anymore. In your post, you declared 'mergedArray' and 'counter' outside the method, correct? I don't see how else you get the 2 and 5 at the end of your example.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see with the code is when the two arrays do not have same length. In either case of (array1.length > array2.length or reverse) the remaining elements of longer array will not be processed. So if you add a more code at end of this the loops to deal with that case, this might work well!

```
public List<Integer> getMergedArray(List<Integer> array1, List<Integer> array2) {
    List<Integer> mergedArray = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {

        for (j = counter; j < array2.size(); j++) {
            if (array1.get(i) > array2.get(j)) {
                mergedArray.add(array2.get(j));
                counter++;
            } else {
                mergedArray.add(array1.get(i));
                System.out.println("i "  +i);
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    // More code here
    if (j==array2.size()){//copy rest of array1 into mergedArray}
    if (i==array1.size()){//copy rest of array2 into mergedArray}


    return mergedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it works but problem is that you don't handle case when inner array size is equal or bigger than size of outer array. I rewrote your method (in way I think it`s right). Hope you'll find it useful.

```
public List<Integer> getMergedArray(List<Integer> array1, List<Integer> array2) {

    List<Integer> mergedArray = new ArrayList<>();

    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.size() + array2.size(); i++) {
        Integer num1 = null;
        Integer num2 = null;
        if (index1 < array1.size()) {
            num1 = array1.get(index1);
        }
        if (index2 < array2.size()) {
            num2 = array2.get(index2);
        }
        if (num1 != null && num2 != null) {
            if (num1 < num2) {
                mergedArray.add(num1);
                ++index1;
            } else {
                mergedArray.add(num2);
                ++index2;
            }
        } else if (num1 != null) {
            mergedArray.add(num1);
            ++index1;
        } else  {
            mergedArray.add(num2);
            ++index2;
        }
    }

    return mergedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array2 has all the element less then array1[i]
in this case your logic also fails because your inner loop condition always fail

you can do this way

int i = 0, j = 0;

```
    int k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (arry1[i] <= arry2[j]) {
            TempArry[k] = arry1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            TempArry[k] = arry2[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy remaining elements of array1[] if any */
    while (i < n1) {
        TempArry[k] = array1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
```